# Calculate shortest distance from point to polygon according angle table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, angles

I have a point in polygon. I want to have new polyline shapefile, which will show the shortest distance from the point to polygon edge, according to given angles in the table.

[image]

Comment: I tried "Bearing Distance To Line" in ArcMap, but it asks for distance also

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with that requested information.

Comment: Use bearing distance to line with 5000 km length, clip result by polygon

Comment: @FelixIP With only an extra couple of sentences I think your comment would make a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

INPUTS:

[image]

PROCESS:

```
arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management("aTable","../p2lines.shp", "POINT_X", "POINT_Y", "Distance", "METERS", "Bearing", "DEGREES", "RHUMB_LINE")
arcpy.Clip_analysis("p2lines", "POLYGON","../clipped.shp")
arcpy.AddField_management("clipped", "LENGTH", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("clipped", "LENGTH","!Shape!.length", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

RESULT:

[image]